# How to convert .xlsx file to encoding utf-8?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, xlsx

I have Excel file somefile.xlsx, i want convet this file to encoding utf-8 ? please tell, how to make this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? My new favorite comment for questions like these!!

Comment: I dont know excel.
In my .xlsx file is not english symbols, I want save this file as .csv extension, when i save file as .csv, in csv file not english symbols  displayed as question marks (????????), I think this problem is from encoding, i want convert file in encoding utf-8, but i dont know what to make ? can you help me?